# Mock empty HTTP response in pytest

Tags: python, https, pytest, requests-mock

I work regularly with a third party API that intermittently responds with the following raw HTTPS response:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: spaghetti.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

ie no status_code, no content, nada. I'm working on some code that will, when faced with this response, retry the request up to three times (with exponential backoff). I'm struggling to mock the response in pytest. I've seen this empty response manifest in my code is a AttributeError that occurs after code like this:

```
response = requests.get('url.com/spaghetti').json()
response.get('data')
```

which results in

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

In an effort to create a mock response that will have the same behavior (ie return `None` when `.json()` is invoked, I tried setting up my test with this mock:

```
requests_mock.get(BASE_URL + '/spaghetti', json=json.dumps(None))
```

However, this mocked `response.json()` is not returning `None` but rather `'null'`

Any advice on how I can mock this strange response so it will return an object with a `.json()` method that returns `None`?
Further, does anyone have any thoughts as to how this response doesn't completely error out in an HTTPS library?

Comment: What if you just did not add the `json` attribute? So instead of `requests_mock.get(BASE_URL + '/spaghetti', json=json.dumps(None))` you used `requests_mock.get(BASE_URL + '/spaghetti')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a valid case because `json.loads()` never returns `None`, however you can do something like this

```
import requests
import json

def test_empty_http(requests_mock, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(json, "loads", lambda kwargs: None)
    requests_mock.get('http://url', json=None)
    assert requests.get('http://url').json() is None
```

Comment: Not sure if this counts as the answer... I did end up using a similar approach. But I disagree that `json.loads()` never returns none, because I'm getting a NoneType error at runtime.

Comment: Both `json.loads("")` and `json.loads(None)` raise exceptions, only `json.loads("null")` (not your case), returns `None`